# How can I reduce my if statements and shorten my code?

Tags: python, if-statement, refactoring

My code works, however, an error pops up saying there are too many statements.

I don't know how to reduce the statements because each one serves a purpose in the function.

```py
def is_sink(elevation_map: List[List[int]], cell: List[int]) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if cell exists in the elevation map
    elevation_map and cell is a sink.

    Precondition: elevation_map is a valid elevation map.
                  cell is a 2-element list.

    >>> is_sink(THREE_BY_THREE, [0, 5])
    False
    >>> is_sink(THREE_BY_THREE, [0, 2])
    True
    >>> is_sink(THREE_BY_THREE, [1, 1])
    False
    >>> is_sink(FOUR_BY_FOUR, [2, 3])
    True
    >>> is_sink(FOUR_BY_FOUR, [3, 2])
    True
    >>> is_sink(FOUR_BY_FOUR, [1, 3])
    False
    """    
    x = cell[0]
    y = cell[1]
    x_initial = 0
    x_final = 0
    y_initial = 0
    y_final = 0

    if x > len(elevation_map): 
        return False
    elif y > len(elevation_map[0]): 
        return False 
    if x - 1 < 0:
        x_initial = x
    else:
        x_initial = x - 1
    if x + 1 >= x:
        x_final = x
    else:
        x_final = x + 1
    if y - 1 < 0:
        y_initial = y
    else:
        y_initial = y - 1
    if y + 1 >= y:
        y_final = y
    else:
        y_final = y + 1
    validsink = True
    for i in range(x_initial, x_final + 1):
        for j in range(y_initial, y_final + 1):
            if elevation_map[i][j] < elevation_map[x][y]:
                validsink = False
    return validsink
```

R0915 (too-many-statements)  Number of occurrences: 1.
  [Line 142] Too many statements (24/20)

Comment: There's no general limit on the number of statements in a function. Is this a restriction imposed by your teacher or a coding competition?

Comment: `if x + 1 >= x:` Is that what you really meant to write? That will always be true. You have a similar statement using `y`.

Comment: Looks like a linter warning, `pylint` has a message similar to this (although I can't tell if it's `pylint` specifically)

Comment: Yes my teacher is limiting the amount of if statements

Comment: You should return from the function as soon as the `for` loops find an invalid link, rather than continuing to loop.

Comment: Notice that your code for getting `x_initial` and `x_final` from `x` is the same as for getting `y_initial` and `y_final` from `y`. You can move that logic into a function, so you only have to write each `if` statement once.

Comment: Your first `if...elif` can also be combined into `if x > len(elevation_map) or y > len(elevation_map[0]):`

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a py-lint warning, suggesting your code is trying to do too much in one routine.  Not really an error, but it does point to less-than-ideal coding practice.

You can reduce a few things in there.

```
if x - 1 < 0:
    x_initial = x
else:
    x_initial = x - 1
```

can become

```
x_initial = x if x - 1 < 0 else x - 1
```

and so on for x_final, y_initial, and y_final.